# django channel async function run in sequence

Tags: django, asynchronous, async-await, django-channels

i was trying  to the  write the  message to database after  group  send  function  in  channels.  But rather  than completing the  group  send  function  it  executes the  group send function pauses the function  in between executes the database write function  and then executes the  group  send 
 which adds delay  in  group  send function. is there is any way to run the  group  send function  to complete first

```
await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': final_message_data
        }
    )
await self.create_chat_message(user, message_data['msg'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this function wrapped in an Asynchronous function ? Otherwise await won't work.

```
async def chat_message(self, event):
  """
  Called when someone has messaged our chat.
  """
  # Send a message down to the client
  await self.send_json(
    {
      "msg_type": settings.MSG_TYPE_MESSAGE,
      "room": event["room_id"],
      "username": event["username"],
      "message": event["message"],
    },
  )
```